# jquery Ajax call successful but error call back being invoked

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why is the following jQuery ajax always calling the error callback even when Fiddler is reporting no errors:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search?format=json&viewbox=-122%2C46%2C-73%2C40&countrycodes=ca&bounded=1&addressdetails=0&q=[hotel]",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'json_callback',
        error: function(parameters) {
            alert(parameters);
        },
        success: searchCompleteCallBack
    });
```

This is the Fiddler session, which although successful, has an a red circle with a line across as the status icon as shown below:
[image]

```
GET /nominatim/v1/search?format=json&viewbox=-122%2C46%2C-73%2C40&countrycodes=ca&bounded=1&addressdetails=0&q=[hotel]&json_callback=jQuery17108850838504386628_1334974646679&_=1334974661295 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/javascript, */*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost:50383/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; BOIE9;ENGB)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: open.mapquestapi.com
Connection: Keep-Alive


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 21 Apr 2012 02:17:41 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Location: search.php
Vary: negotiate
TCN: choice
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 4775
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=91
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

jQuery17108850838504386628_1334974646679([{"place_id":"2166467243","licence":"Data Copyright OpenStreetMap Contributors, Some Rights Reserved. CC-BY-SA 2.0.","osm_type":"node","osm_id":"1417990074","boundingbox":["43.0738813782","43.0938851929","-79.0912683105","-79.0712606812"],"lat":"43.0838817","lon":"-79.0812662","display_name":"Quality Hotel, Murray Street, Niagara Falls, Ontario, Ontario, Canada","class":"tourism","type":"hotel","icon":"http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/images/mapicons/accommodation_hotel2.p.20.png"},{"place_id":"2085733959","licence":"Data Copyright OpenStreetMap Contributors, Some Rights Reserved. CC-BY-SA 2.0.","osm_type":"way","osm_id":"97928121","boundingbox":["49.8510055541992","49.8513870239258","-97.1532821655273","-97.1526718139648"],"lat":"49.8512060913871","lon":"-97.1530114466667","display_name":"Pembina Hotel, 1011, Pembina Highway, Point Road, Winnipeg, Manitoba, Canada","class":"amenity","type":"hotel"},{"place_id":"2152638544","licence":"Data Copyright OpenStreetMap Contributors, Some Rights Reserved. CC-BY-SA 2.0.","osm_type":"node","osm_id":"1324405899","boundingbox":["43.8393080139","43.8593118286","-79.3921792603","-79.3721716309"],"lat":"43.849309","lon":"-79.382178","display_name":"Holiday Inn Express & Suites, Fulton Way, Thornlea, Markham, Ontario","class":"tourism","type":"hotel","icon":"http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/images/mapicons/accommodation_hotel2.p.20.png"},{"place_id":"2177668535","licence":"Data Copyright OpenStreetMap Contributors, Some Rights Reserved. CC-BY-SA 2.0.","osm_type":"way","osm_id":"138157978","boundingbox":["43.4092330932617","43.4098968505859","-80.3297119140625","-80.3289260864258"],"lat":"43.40953956119","lon":"-80.3293440133707","display_name":"Hespeler Road, Cambridge, Ontario, Canada","class":"tourism","type":"hotel","icon":"http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/images/mapicons/accommodation_hotel2.p.20.png"},{"place_id":"2138545308","licence":"Data Copyright OpenStreetMap Contributors, Some Rights Reserved. CC-BY-SA 2.0.","osm_type":"node","osm_id":"1280026038","boundingbox":["43.6322805786","43.6522843933","-79.4218270874","-79.401819458"],"lat":"43.6422834","lon":"-79.4118234","display_name":"Palace Arms, Strachan Avenue, Liberty Village, Toronto, Ontario, M5A1Z9, Canada","class":"tourism","type":"hostel"},{"place_id":"5773486","licence":"Data Copyright OpenStreetMap Contributors, Some Rights Reserved. CC-BY-SA 2.0.","osm_type":"node","osm_id":"583902387","boundingbox":["45.3422987366","45.3623025513","-75.6427056885","-75.6226980591"],"lat":"45.3522996","lon":"-75.6327046","display_name":"Bank Street, Blossom Park, Ottawa, Ontario","class":"tourism","type":"hotel","icon":"http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/images/mapicons/accommodation_hotel2.p.20.png"},{"place_id":"2170250899","licence":"Data Copyright OpenStreetMap Contributors, Some Rights Reserved. CC-BY-SA 2.0.","osm_type":"node","osm_id":"1445914835","boundingbox":["43.1746237183","43.194627533","-79.5842340088","-79.5642263794"],"lat":"43.1846249","lon":"-79.5742298","display_name":"Beamer Falls Manor at Falconridge Farm, Ridge Road West, Grimsby, Ontario, Canada","class":"tourism","type":"hotel","icon":"http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/images/mapicons/accommodation_hotel2.p.20.png"},{"place_id":"2664364","licence":"Data Copyright OpenStreetMap Contributors, Some Rights Reserved. CC-BY-SA 2.0.","osm_type":"node","osm_id":"343055090","boundingbox":["43.6355078125","43.6555116272","-79.4053170776","-79.3853094482"],"lat":"43.6455088","lon":"-79.3953127","display_name":"Global Village Backpackers Hostel, King Street West, Fashion District, Toronto, Ontario, M5A1Z9, Canada","class":"tourism","type":"hostel"},{"place_id":"2168185190","licence":"Data Copyright OpenStreetMap Contributors, Some Rights Reserved. CC-BY-SA 2.0.","osm_type":"way","osm_id":"129431482","boundingbox":["45.3853416442871","45.3861045837402","-75.733268737793","-75.7327346801758"],"lat":"45.3857092561038","lon":"-75.7330025913023","display_name":"Best Western Macies Hotel, Carling Avenue, Rideauview, Ottawa, Ontario, Canada","class":"tourism","type":"hotel","icon":"http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/images/mapicons/accommodation_hotel2.p.20.png"},{"place_id":"2166467244","licence":"Data Copyright OpenStreetMap Contributors, Some Rights Reserved. CC-BY-SA 2.0.","osm_type":"node","osm_id":"1417990095","boundingbox":["43.0724356079","43.0924394226","-79.0928704834","-79.072862854"],"lat":"43.0824382","lon":"-79.0828672","display_name":"Hilton Niagara Falls, Fallsview Boulevard, Niagara Falls, Ontario, Ontario, Canada","class":"tourism","type":"hotel","icon":"http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/images/mapicons/accommodation_hotel2.p.20.png"}])
```

I actually had this working not too long ago but cannot figure out what i am doing wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce the problem in neither Firefox nor Chrome.

Try this piece of code in your console and see what's happened.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search?format=json&viewbox=-122%2C46%2C-73%2C40&countrycodes=ca&bounded=1&addressdetails=0&q=[hotel]",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'json_callback',
        error: function(parameters) {
            console.error("error");
            console.error(parameters);
        },
        success: function(parameters) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(parameters);
        },
    });
```

And I got this:

```
XMLHttpRequest
success
[
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
]
```

Comment: What console is this?  The Chrome console gives me nothing. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Then press Ctrl + Shift + J, you'll see a Javascript console.

Comment: Yes, using Chrome.  Did that, executed script but console shows just a buhcn of warning like this:  Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://localhost:50383/Content/themes/base/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png".  Maybe I be looking at security settings on this Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client?  Looks like things stopped working after Cisco was installed.

Comment: If your error callback is called, you can expand its parameters to see what's happened. You may want to check parameters.status and parameters.statusText.

Comment: If I subscribe to a the .ajaxError event, it is not called, which also means I am not getting an error.  But, error call back is being invoked.

Comment: ... just to add, error I can getting is "jQuery17104061470480989598_1335126561380 was not called".

Comment: Which jquery version are you using?

Comment: 1.7.2.  Still trying to figure this out by looking at the jQuery source.  I am getting the failure only under a specific scenario, so suspecting my window object getting out f scope..

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery-1.7.2.js, there is a gray area from when the dynamic jsonp request script is loaded (line 8123 thereabouts) to when a response is received from the server and the callback installed on line 8016 is invoked.  It appears as though this call back, even though defined in a global scope on the window object, does not exist under certain circumstances.  Layout of children elements under this window object does have something to do with it as invoking ajax by clicking on a checkbox laid directly on an ASP.NET razor partial view works but when invoked from a button within an OpenLayers.Popup.FrameCloud you run into this problem.

A workaround is to prevent jQuery from defining a random function as the jsonp callback as follows:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search?format=json&viewbox=-122%2C46%2C-73%2C40&countrycodes=ca&bounded=1&addressdetails=0&q=[hotel]&json_callback=onSearchComplete",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        error: function(parameters) {
            alert(parameters);
        }
    });
```

where in this case 'onSearchComplete' is a global function defined in your script.  With this setup, onSearchComplete will always be called upon successful server response, regardless of how the ajax query is invoked.  Problem in this case is that jQuery still creates and installs the randomly named callback function even though it is not being sent as part of the json request.  As a result, the randomly generated callback will never be executed and causing jQuery to treat this as an error condition.

Maybe the jQuery gurus can shed more light here.